# Change to and from speaker using CallKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudiosession, callkit

I am creating a CallKit app that only does outbound calls.
We are doing our own interface, not using the built in UI.
I need to put a speaker button on the screen that will switch from speaker/no-speaker mode.

I have followed Apple's guidelines and example CallKit code and 
it appears to be working well enough.

I could not find much information on how to switch to and from speaker mode.  I am using the following function to change the audio route.
Does anyone have experience doing this? Will this work reliably?

```
func speaker(on: Bool) {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        // not sure I need this ...
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        if on {
            // does this trigger a change to the audio route?
            try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
        } else {
            // is this how to switch back to the phone speaker?
            try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
        }
    } catch {
        // Audio session change failure
        print("failed to change speaker phone")
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean you have problem with UI?

Comment: I can deal with the UI just fine. What I want to know is how to tell it to use the different speakers.

Comment: Hii 

@ryantxr , you got any solution, i'm also facing same problem.

Comment: I have not. It turns out that my app does not need that yet.

Comment: Hi @ryantxr Do you have solution for UI updation of speaker button normal & selected in Callkit?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the following at the end of your do block: `audioSession.setActive(true)`